# Не работает addClass() И removeClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке шапка закреплялась сверху страницы и уменьшалась, но в js-файле webstorm не видит функцию addClass и removeClass. Код:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('#header').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('#header').remove("sticky");
    }
})
```

```css
header{
    background: url('../logo_new2.png') no-repeat center top;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    /*Анимация сжатия*/

    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
header.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">                 
        <header class="header">
        </header>
</div>
```

**Обновлено:**

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
            $('#header').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('#header').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    })
```

Comment: Во-первых, в вашем коде нет функции removeClass. Во-вторых, что значит не видит?

Comment: Пишет, что addClass unresolved function or method. То же пишет и для removeClass

Comment: Да, действительно. Спасибо

Comment: Изменение #header на :header не помогло.

Comment: @Офисный_рабочий, поменяйте на `.header`

Comment: @Node_pro, это тоже не помогло

Comment: что инмнно не помогло - https://jsfiddle.net/pdv7ywsa/

Comment: При изменении $('#header').addClass("sticky"); на $('.header').addClass("sticky"); и $(':header').addClass("sticky"); Webstorm все равно не считает функции addClass() и removeClass() за функции.

Comment: вы сходили по ссылке?

Comment: jquery вообще подключен ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, да

Comment: пишите не #header а .header

Comment: @Офисный_рабочий, если файл jQuery подключен удаленно он его спокойной может не видеть. Либо если файл подключен за проектом. Но это не влияет на работу скрипта. Скрипт рабочий,

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том, что header начинал прыгать из-за того, что при вызове removeClass() для header'а просто не было места (место уменьшалось при вызове addClass()). Пришлось добавить добавить дополнительные атрибуты отступа для CSS-класс header.sticky.

**Решение:**

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
            $('header').addClass("sticky");
            $("body").css({
                "paddingTop": $('header').height()
            })
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass("sticky");
            $("body").css({
                "paddingTop": "0"
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: Ответ непонятен прям совсем